# How to get Roles For Users in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles, asp.net-identity-2

I have MVC 5 app that I am upgrading to MVC 6. I am stumped on this one line in building a List of Users and sub-List of Roles for each user.

**This works in MVC 5 version of app:**

```
    // GET: /UserManagement
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(GetUsers());
    }
private List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
{
    return context.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
    {
        Email = u.Email,
        UserId = u.Id,
        Roles = u.Roles.Select(rs => context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == rs.RoleId)).Select(rs2 => rs2.Name).ToList()
    }).ToList();

}
```

**However when moved over to MVC 6 version, it will only show the Index View and List of Users if I comment out the "Roles =" line above.**

```
//Roles = u.Roles.Select(rs => context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == rs.RoleId)).Select(rs2 => rs2.Name).ToList()
```

View comes up with users in rows, looks great, but no roles list.
If I don't comment out the Roles line, I get this error:

ArgumentException: Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer'

I have no idea how to implement a list inside of list like what was done in the MVC 5 version (the person is no longer available that wrote the MVC 5 code).
Now, I have fixed numerous items in the MVC 6 version but this one has me stumped. Any answer that will get me rows of users and their roles I would accept. Not picky, just trying to survive.

Just in case you need to see the View, here is the fieldset that contains the rows that loads and fills except for Roles list:

```
<fieldset>
    <table id="users" class="display">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Email</th>
                <th width="20%">Roles</th>
                <th width="20%">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (null != Model)
            {
                foreach (var user in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (null != user.Roles)
                            {
                                foreach (var role in user.Roles)
                                {
                                    @role
                                    <br />
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { userId = user.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { userId = user.UserId }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')", @class = "btn btn-default" })

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

And I better include the UserViewModel.cs that gets used. I know very little about why or how this is used. Pretty sure the User and Roles come from the Identity Tables (the ones prefixed with AspNet)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MVC6.Models
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Looks like MVC 5 and 6 both do User and Roles very differently from what I'm used to.  Have you had a look at this article?  http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingauthmembership.html

Comment: Yes. It is already obsolete and doesn't deal with User/Roles management. 
I found the IServiceProvider to be very helpful in dealing with other Role and User Actions, but dumbfounded here because of the list inside of a list. The "function" gets all the Users. I just can't figure the syntax for getting the roles and associating them with each user. MVC 5 version works but I'm thinking maybe having to rebuild this one view from the ground up.